# Is it possible to use await with query that uses custom function

Tags: c#, .net, linq, async-await, entity-framework-6

I would like to wait for this query before proceeding to do anything else. I have seen several question on this topic but none of those are using custom function in the query, which is making it little tricky. Is it even possible to use await with following query. I am using await-async in .NET4.0 using Microsoft Async package.(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)

```
var Employees = 
    (from d in context.Employees
    join a in context.Address on d.ID equals a.EmployeeID
    select new 
    {
        Employee = d,
        Address = a,
    })
    .AsEnumerable() memory
    .Select(x => new Employee
    {
        Id = x.Employee.Id,
        PreferredName = GetPreferredName(x.Employee.FirstName, x.Employee.MiddleName, x.Employee.LastName, x.Employee.Alias),
        StreetAddress = x.Address.StreetAddress 
    })
    .ToList();

private string GetPreferredName(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName, string dnsName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
            return firstName;
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName))
                return middleName;
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
                return lastName;
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dnsName))
                return dnsName;

            return "";
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ToListAsync` to asynchronously get the results of an EF query.

```
var query = await
    (from d in context.Employees
    join a in context.Address on d.ID equals a.EmployeeID
    select new 
    {
        Employee = d,
        Address = a,
    })
    .ToListAsync();

var Employees = query    
    .Select(x => new Employee
    {
        Id = x.Employee.Id,
        PreferredName = GetPreferredName(x.Employee.FirstName, x.Employee.MiddleName, x.Employee.LastName, x.Employee.Alias),
        StreetAddress = x.Address.StreetAddress 
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `await` using [`ToListAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) instead of `ToList()` if you invoke your first part of the query before bringing it in to memory:

```
var queryEmployees = await
(from d in context.Employees
join a in context.Address on d.ID equals a.EmployeeID
select new 
{
    Employee = d,
    Address = a,
}).ToListAsync();

var employees = Employees.Select(x => new Employee
{
    Id = x.Employee.Id,
    PreferredName = GetPreferredName(x.Employee.FirstName, x.Employee.MiddleName, x.Employee.LastName, x.Employee.Alias),
    StreetAddress = x.Address.StreetAddress 
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: @Servy Yeah, didn't notice the `AsEnumerable` inside the query. Fixed.